# Not able to pass route parameter defined in group to routes in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm learning PHP Laravel and stuck at a very basic thing. I need to have routes like

- GET /api/projects
- GET /api/projects/56
- DEL /api/projects/57

so I defined my routes like this

```php
Route::prefix("projects")
    ->group(function(): void {
        Route::get("/", [ProjectsController::class, "all"]);
        Route::post("/", [ProjectsController::class, "add"]);

        Route::prefix("/{projectid}")
            ->where(["projectid"=>"[0..9]+"])
            ->group(function($projectid){
                Route::get("/", [ProjectsController::class, "one"]);
                Route::put("/", [ProjectsController::class, "update"]);
                Route::delete("/", [ProjectsController::class, "delete"]);
            });
    });
```

and my controller is defined like this:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
class ProjectsController extends SecureController
{
    public function all()
    {
        return "projects";
    }

    public function one(int $projectid)
    {
        return "project " . $projectid;
    }
    public function add(int $projectid)
    {

    }
    public function update(int $projectid)
    {

    }

    public function delete(int $projectid)
    {

    }
}
```

But when I try to run I get this:

> 404 not found

I made a minor change

```php
Route::prefix("projects")
    ->group(function(): void {
        Route::get("/", [ProjectsController::class, "all"]);
        Route::post("/", [ProjectsController::class, "add"]);

        Route::prefix("/{projectid}")
            ->where(["projectid"=>"[0..9]+"])
            ->group(function(int $projectid){
                Route::get("/", [ProjectsController::class, "one"]);
                Route::put("/", [ProjectsController::class, "update"]);
                Route::delete("/", [ProjectsController::class, "delete"]);
            });
    });
```

and now PHP does not run it:

> Illuminate\Routing\RouteFileRegistrar::{closure}(): Argument #1 ($projectid) must be of type int, Illuminate\Routing\Router given, called in /projects/php/project-doctor/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php on line 502

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd just eliminate the confusion and make 3 separate project routes with the actual route instead of using the prefix. Also of note, you can use [`->whereNumber('projectid')`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints) instead of doing your own regex

Comment: the error is in this line _->group(function(int $projectid){_

Comment: Right. Ignore the grouping, just do `Route::get("/{projectid}", [ProjectsController::class, "one"])->whereNumber('projectid');`

Comment: what if I have 20 routes? do i need to repeat it for every route? that would be insane

Comment: You're still doing the routes, anyway, this just eliminates the confusion with the prefix.

Comment: Are you trying to create route binding per projectid? Because it seems like you are trying to group them under projectid. Why not simple just create simple routes somthing like this
`Route::get('projects/{projectid}/', [ProjectsController::class, "one"]);`
`Route::put('projects/{projectid}/', [ProjectsController::class, "update"]);`
`Route::delete('projects/{projectid}/', [ProjectsController::class, "delete"]);`

Comment: Also please have a look on a standard practice of grouping, usually grouping is performed when say example all routes under it deal with user authentication. In your case, it would be just prefix but if you ignore that and add it directly to route as well it will do.

Comment: @Adi if i do it the way you said, which is the same as others said, then the constraint for the _{projectid}_ has to be defined with every route using _where()_ Don't know but DRY principle is in violation here

Comment: Well actually it's still using same LOC and no harm repeating routes though. But you can try something like this then i haven't tested this yet
`Route::group([
    'prefix'     => '/{projectid}'
], function () {
    // Project routes here
});`